# Porque no me imprime los datos de la Base de datos asignado a variable Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

**Por que muestra error de **Notice**:  Array to string conversion in C:**

**Inspertor**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Inspertor**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  <script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
      <?php 
         $consulta="SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
         $resultado=$conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

         while ($paisBuscado=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
       ?>  
          var paisBuscado = "<?php echo $paisBuscado; ?>";
          document.write(paisBuscado);

   <?php  
     }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Pon `var_dump($paisBuscado)` para ver que sale de la variable.

Comment: Me aparece esto por cada variable encontrada en la base de datos     array(1) {  ["idCategoria"]=> string(15) "Muros al Maximo"
}

Comment: Entonces dejalo asi "<?php echo $paisBuscado[\"idCategoria\"]; ?>";

Answer (score 1):

Asumiento que lo que te retorna es una arreglo es mejor si lo trabajas de esta manera

```
var paisBuscado = <?php echo json_encode($paisBuscado); ?>
```

en el caso de que tengas un resultado deberias poder acceder a los datos con paisBuscado.idCategoria por ejemplo.

pero si el es un solo valor el tema deberia ser.

```
var paisBuscado = "<?php echo $paisBuscado['idCategoria'] ?>";
```

espero te pueda ayudar y el error es porque intentas convertir un arreglo a un string.

Comment: ya lo hice como me indicaste pero solo se muetra la variables dentro de la venta de los errores de js y no me lo imprime en el documento

Comment: prove en quitarle  <script>
    $('document').ready(function() { ]</script>. Y me muestra todo pero al poner esto me manda al error de js

Comment: Bueno lo que necesitas en que lo imprima en el documento ?, puedes si ya te imprime la variable en la consola por asi decirlo puedes darle el manejo que quieras y te deberia funcionar por ejemplo al poner console.log(paisBuscado) te sale el pais esta bien tendrias que procesar el valor no se por ejmplo  poner algo como $('.nombreClaseDiv').html(paisBuscado)

Answer (score 1):

Si le haces `echo` a un array siempre habrá un error de Array to string conversion.

Debieses hacer, en cambio:

```
var paisBuscado = "<?php echo $paisBuscado['idCategoria']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate al parecer `or die` está pegado al paréntesis izquierdo, no se si te equivocaste al pegar el código, o si así está tipeado. capaz y por eso no te funciona, ya que al parecer está bien la sintaxis.